# How do I implement Firebase Cloud messaging on a webapp?

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

All examples on codelabs use GCM and firebase docs link to codelabs example [Here is the link to the code lab guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en). I tried following as best i could and kept getting 401 error